# jqplot help for barclustered type chart

Tags: jqplot

hFollowing is the code for barclustered jqplot. can anyone please guide me gow to create a highlighted array in following code dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// For horizontal bar charts, x an y values must will be "flipped"
// from their vertical bar counterpart.
var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [
    [[2,1], [4,2], [6,3], [3,4]], 
    [[5,1], [1,2], [3,3], [4,4]], 
    [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]], {
       seriesDefaults: {
           renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
           // Show point labels to the right ('e'ast) of each bar.
           // edgeTolerance of -15 allows labels flow outside the grid
           // up to 15 pixels.  If they flow out more than that, they 
           // will be hidden.
           pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
           // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
           shadowAngle: 135,
           // Here's where we tell the chart it is oriented horizontally.
           rendererOptions: {
               barDirection: 'horizontal'
           }
       },
       axes: {
           yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
           }
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure well-understanding what you are looking for ! If you want to add an highlight when your cursor is hover a bar take a look at [Jqplot documentation about highlighter](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html).

Comment: [[[2,1], [4,2], [6,3], [3,4]], 
    [[5,1], [1,2], [3,3], [4,4]], 
    [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]]

I would like to create this part dynamically through an array. please help

Comment: You can assign your data to a variable and use this variable when creating your plot : var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', my_var, {seriesDefaults: .../*jqplot options*/}); . Thus you can create your variable as you want it (what do you mean by create it dynamically though an array?)

Comment: sorry i meant i want to create dynamically an array. can you please write some steps for the same

Comment: But your array has to be created based on what? Random number?

Comment: it is to be created using a java variable which is VData=9,453,470,232|488,378,375,142|365,275,255,434|217,317,479,89

following is the way i am trying to create the thing like mentioned in 2nd comment of this post

  var a=new Array();
   <%for(int m=0;m<VData.split("\\|").length;m++)
   {
   

    for(int j=0;j<VData.split("\\|")[m].split(",").length;j++){
   
    %>  
    a[<%=m%>]=new Array(<%=VData.split("\\|")[m].split(",").length%>);
    a[<%=m%>][<%=j%>]=[<%=VData.split("\\|")[m].split(",")[j]%>,<%=m+1%>];
    
    
    <% } 
    
   }
   %>

Comment: After your loop, what your a variable looks like?

Comment: It should look like [[[2,1], [4,2], [6,3], [3,4]], [[5,1], [1,2], [3,3], [4,4]], [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]] but when I "alert" it looks like 2,1,4,2,6,3,3,4,5,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,1,7,2,1,3,2,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your Javascript syntax and algorithm. The loop should looks like :

```
VData="9,453,470,232|488,378,375,142|365,275,255,434|217,317,479,89";
var a = new Array();
var split_fst = VData.split("|")
for(m=0;m<split_fst.length;m++) { 
  var split_snd = split_fst[m].split(",");
  a[m] = new Array();
  for(j=0;j<split_snd.length;j++){ 
     a[m][j]=split_snd[j];
  }
}
```

Your `a` variable now looks like : `[["9","453","470","232"],["488","378","375","142"],["365","275","255","434"],["217","317","479","89"]]